# Mouse-listener that stops a block from executing when the mouse is released

Tags: java, mouselistener, mouse-listeners

In Java, I need  to integrate a mouse Listener that moves a motor. However here is the catch, there is no stop function. Thereby, the mousepressed should move the motor, while the mouseReleased should stop it, without actually sending a stop command but rather by stopping the mouse pressed block from executing. Any ideas on how this can be implemented? And is it possible to repeat the command under mousePressed as long as the mouse is pressed?
The following code is to illustrate my current program, which uses a stop function, which i would rather avoid.

```
    n2Button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if ((e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) != 0) {
                try {
                    //                        moveUp();
                    session.motion(0, 0, -500);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if ((e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) != 0) {
                try {
                    session.stop();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You rather want to have mouse motion listener
[Example][1]  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html
And i also do not see the problem to have  session.stop(); only the movement function i guess must be executed in another thread

Comment: Unfortunately in my case there is no stop function (can not be implemented). The above snippet was used with a previous version of a motor that would move (taking speed as a parameter) until it would receive a stop command. In this new version, it moves for eg. 0.001mm every time you command it, and there is no stop function. I don't believe motion listener would help me anyways. I want to implement it with an actionlistener.

Comment: Hence, as long as i press the button i want it to resent the move 0.001mm command and as soon as I release it, to stop sending this command. Any ideas?

Comment: Mouse dragged is what you need. 
'    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
       saySomething("Mouse dragged", e);
    }

    void saySomething(String eventDescription, MouseEvent e) {
        textArea.append(eventDescription 
                        + " (" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY() + ")"
                        + " detected on "
                        + e.getComponent().getClass().getName()
                        + newline);
    }'

Comment: Instead of printing out, you use this coordinates to paint your motor.
about a button, overwrite a common public void actionPerformed, to start a **new thread**, a GUI-one if you need, and in this thread you are repainting a motor, do not forget, to make some delay for example with Thread.sleep().

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wasn't aware of this function. Gimme a day to come back to you! ; )